# How to securely run automated paramiko ssh tasks in python when password is required?

Tags: python, security, ssh, passwords

So I have setup a little test SSH server and I can successfully access it with Paramiko. In production I will be required to supply a password at each ssh connection. However, if I want to initiate a bunch of tasks it seems like I need to hardcode the password in to a .py text file. This, of course, is a terrible idea, but the only solution I can think of is to prompt the user for the password every time the ssh connection is made. I thought about trying to hash the password, but the whole point is that the ssh connection requires the plain text version of the password, so that won't work. Another idea is to ask for login information at the beginning of the script, and the execute the code, then delete from memory, but I am not sure how secure that is either.

Is there a best practice way to use passwords with python ssh connections?

Comment: I think you would want to use getpass. Prompt for it at the beginning of the script and pass it around. If you want to hash it for longer term usage, you would need to make a function to convert it to plain text, use it, and remove it. Otherwise, set up ssh key pairs and don't worry about passwords.